# How do I create API to third party website?

Tags: python, api

my company uses a third party website to track and store our orders and delivery statistics. I've asked them about API access to our data but the never reply. Is it possible I create an API myself to automate access to our data? Instances of APIs created I've seen online seem to be in cases where the website owners create it themselves. They use information like database name, or data URL (e.g url.json) that I don't have.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. REST API access or direct database access has to be provided by the host, not the client(you).

If you have access to the data via a web frontend, you can try to work around that limitation by parsing the web pages. Look into [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)